# Encode and Decode the string ( 'latin-1') and parse to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encode

I am trying to parse string into JSON, the strings are the data I **scrape** from news API. But I face lots of encoding errors. I try to use `ftfy.fix_text`, replace the symbol manually. But it is endless... Always pops up new error:

```
'latin-1' codec can't encode character
```

The latest error is because of this string: `'CoachHub the Berlin-based digital coaching platform raises €10M from existing investors HV Holtzbrinck Ventures Partech and others (Thomas Ohr/EU-Startups)'`

I've tried: `s = s.encode('cp1252')` But it then says: `can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str` in line 5

I also tried:`s = s.encode('utf-8')`. The error is same as using cp152.

Here is my code:

```
s =  text[i]
s = ftfy.fix_text(s)
s = s.replace('—', '-')
s = s.replace('"',"'")
y = '{"id": "123", "text" : "' + s + '", "userId": "123" , "timestamp" :  "2019/10/25", "applications" : "fb"}'
r = requests.post(url, data=y)
data = r.json()
```

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: @Uber When I use str() on above sentence: `CoachHub the Berlin-based digital coaching platform raises`, it still shows the error: ` 'latin-1' codec can't encode character`

Comment: The string ought to be serialisable to JSON without doing any encoding - could you [edit] your question to include the output of `print(repr(text[i]))` so we can see exactly what data you are working with?